# How is $event used in "Logic hooks"?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I see this example code that contains a method called StampIt that has 2 arguments $focus and $event

```
class AddTimeStamp
{
    function StampIt(& $focus, $event)
    {
        global $current_user;
        $focus->description .= "Saved on ". date("Y-m-d g:i a"). " by ". $current_user->user_name;         }
}
```

I'm just trying to understand where $event argument is used since it's not mentioned anywhere inside the StampIt method

source: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Module_Builder/Introduction/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$event` will contain the name of the currently executing event/hook type during runtime.
This is useful if a single method is hooked into more than one event and needs to alter its logic based on what event triggered it.

In this particular example we know that `$event` will always contain the string `before_safe` as this is the only event our example method has been hooked into. No other event will ever call that method.

That is why the variable remains unused in this example, as the method does not have to handle more than that single event type anyway and would also not gain any new information by reading `$event`.